# Code generating negative numbers while trying to generate unique int64

Tags: go, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create unique int64 using the below Go code

```
unixtimestamp := time.Now().UnixNano()
    node := AppConfig.NodeID << 44
    timestamp := unixtimestamp << 12
    var sequenceID int64
    for sequenceID = 1; sequenceID <= count; sequenceID++ {
        id := node | timestamp | sequenceID
        idList = append(idList, id)
    }
```

The above code is also generating negative numbers. How do I fix it?

Comment: The simplest fix is to convert the `int64` value to `uint64`. The correct fix? We need to know more about your algorithm and values involved in it.

Comment: @icza Thanks, I am trying to generate unique int64 for a db table unique bigint column

Comment: To make a negative number positive multiplying by -1 works for almost all cases.

Comment: @Volker Does it guarantee the uniqueness

Comment: If your negative numbers are uniq than multiplying them by any number != 0 won't make them un-nuique, especially not if multiplied by -1 as this won't (in almost all cases) overflow. I guess your way of generating "uniq" numbers is deeply flawed and them being negative is by far your smallest problem.

Comment: If you need to ensure unique values, `time.Now().UnixNano()` is not correct. Multiple calls within the system clock's minimum resolution (which is system dependent) will yield the same result. If you need a random number, use a real random number.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's negative make it positive:

```
unixtimestamp := time.Now().UnixNano()
node := AppConfig.NodeID << 44
timestamp := unixtimestamp << 12
var sequenceID int64
for sequenceID = 1; sequenceID <= count; sequenceID++ {
    id := node | timestamp | sequenceID
    if id < 0 {
        id = id *  -1
    }
    idList = append(idList, id)
}
```